# How to find dominant pixel count of one raster in another raster with different cell size?

Tags: python, raster, zonal-statistics

I have one raster that is categorical values for land cover classes (from the NLCD) at 30m resolution. I also have another raster for land surface temperature (LST) data at 70m resolution. I would like to find the dominant NLCD class in each LST pixel. For example, if there are 4 NLCD pixels in a single LST pixel, I would like to find the NLCD class  with the most occurences.

I would prefer Python, but would accept an answer in R (since it has become very popular for Raster analysis).

Test dataset located at:
https://github.com/arojas314/data-sharing/blob/main/nlcd2019_nyc.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach with R

```
library(terra)
nlcd = rast("nlcd2019_nyc.tif")
lst = rast("lst_scaled_temp.tif")

# create a template that matches the extent of lst and 
# approximately the spatial resolution of nlcd
x = disagg(rast(lst), 2)

# nearest neighbor resample nlcd to the template
rnlcd = resample(nlcd, x, "near")

# aggregate to get the dominant value of each lst cell
arnlcd = aggregate(rnlcd, 2, "modal")
arnlcd
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 851, 983, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.0006308342, 0.0006308461  (x, y)
#extent      : -74.30966, -73.68955, 40.41139, 40.94824  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#source      : memory 
#color table : 1 
#name        : Layer_1 
#min value   :       0 
#max value   :      95
```

You do not provide any background info. I wonder if your goal is to summarize lst values by nlcd class. In that case I think it would make more sense to do:

```
rlst = resample(lst, nlcd)
z2 = zonal(rlst, nlcd, mean)
head(z2)
#  Layer_1 lst_scaled_temp
#1       0        283.6699
#2      11        289.6679
#3      21        300.0840
#4      22        301.9470
#5      23        304.7881
#6      24        308.4624
```

Comment: I tend to avoid R since I usually integrate python code into larger programs, but wow this method is easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to co-register two data. since you want dominant value in each cell, i think mode resampling method is suitable for your task. here the python function for co-registering using rasterio.
reference: [co-register](https://pygis.io/docs/e_raster_resample.html#example-of-co-registering-rasters-with-rasterio) (code not mine - i just changed resampling method to *mode*):

```py
from rasterio.warp import reproject, Resampling, calculate_default_transform
import rasterio
def reproj_match(infile, match, outfile):
    """Reproject a file to match the shape and projection of existing raster. 
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    infile : (string) path to input file to reproject
    match : (string) path to raster with desired shape and projection 
    outfile : (string) path to output file tif
    """
    # open input
    with rasterio.open(infile) as src:
        src_transform = src.transform
        
        # open input to match
        with rasterio.open(match) as match:
            dst_crs = match.crs
            
            # calculate the output transform matrix
            dst_transform, dst_width, dst_height = calculate_default_transform(
                src.crs,     # input CRS
                dst_crs,     # output CRS
                match.width,   # input width
                match.height,  # input height 
                *match.bounds,  # unpacks input outer boundaries (left, bottom, right, top)
            )

        # set properties for output
        dst_kwargs = src.meta.copy()
        dst_kwargs.update({"crs": dst_crs,
                           "transform": dst_transform,
                           "width": dst_width,
                           "height": dst_height,
                           "nodata": 0})
        print("Coregistered to shape:", dst_height,dst_width,'\n Affine',dst_transform)
        # open output
        with rasterio.open(outfile, "w", **dst_kwargs) as dst:
            # iterate through bands and write using reproject function
            for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
                reproject(
                    source=rasterio.band(src, i),
                    destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                    src_transform=src.transform,
                    src_crs=src.crs,
                    dst_transform=dst_transform,
                    dst_crs=dst_crs,
                    resampling=Resampling.mode) # mode resampling method
```

I've checked and it seems working.